# sqLite OFFSET query does not work with WHERE clause?

Tags: sqlite, where-clause, offset, sql-limit

Can someone explain why this sqlite3 query will work and return my 1000 records:

```
SELECT * FROM fmsdata LIMIT 1000 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fmsdata) - 1000
```

but the minute I drop in the where clause `WHERE valve=3` it returns nothing?

```
SELECT * FROM fmsdata WHERE valve=3 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fmsdata) - 1000
```

This sub query returns the table size which is 123290.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fmsdata
```

FYI the offset is just to quickly give me the tail end of the database without having to sort anything since I know the latest records will always be at the end.

Here is a successful query without the where clause:

[image: no where clause]

Our test table has records looping roughly around 102 valves so with a limit of 1000 we should have at least 9 entries that showed up at the tail end of the query.

Not sure if it matters but I am on a Ubuntu 18.04 system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM fmsdata WHERE valve=3 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fmsdata) - 1000
```

according to your data, is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM fmsdata WHERE valve=3 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 123290 - 1000
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM fmsdata WHERE valve=3 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 122290
```

and this is translated to:

> From the rows where valve=3, skip the first 122290 and then show me
>   maximum 1000 rows.

Do you have more than 122290 rows where `valve=3`?
I don't think so. This is why you get nothing. 
I think what you really want is this:

```
SELECT * FROM fmsdata WHERE valve=3 
LIMIT 1000 
OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fmsdata WHERE valve=3) - 1000
```

This means if you have 1100 rows where `valve=3`, the first 100 (= 1100 - 1000) will be skipped and the remaining 1000 will be selected.
If you have 1000 or less rows where `valve=3` then all these rows will be selected. 
*As a side note*: 
when you use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` you must be aware that the result is not guaranteed to be accurate.

Comment: Excellent answer. I would  emphasis on your last sentence. OP statement "_FYI the offset is just to quickly give me the tail end of the database without having to sort anything since I know the latest records will always be at the end._" is really where it all goes wrong. @simgineer You should never assume that this `LIMIT` statement without `ORDER BY DESC`, will bring back the last records inserted in the table

Comment: *You should never assume...* this is the point. Anything not documented, even if it seems *obvious* can go wrong.

Comment: Adding the WHERE clause in the sub query fixes everything. I was avoiding the ORDER BY to speed up the query since we knew the records would always be inserted in chronological order for these particular files. I suppose the advise is that once we start using any non trivial operation the actual order is no longer guaranteed. Thank you forpas for this answer.